# Angular does undesired redraw after change of irrelevant Redux state slice

Tags: angular, redux

In my Angular Redux application component A depends on Redux state slice X, but not on Redux state slice Y.
However, when only state slice Y changes, component A is rerendered.

What can I do to avoid that component A is rerendered when only state slice Y changes?

Comment: You could fix it with reducers or selectors but none of them are included in your question. The reducer may needlessly re create state or the selector may re create a result that is not memoized.

Comment: One of the used selectors is
hasDriversWithoutRack$: Observable<boolean> = this.ngRedux.select(state => state.drivers.filter(d => d.rackIndex === undefined).length > 0);
in which the filter creates a new array. But that array is not returned by the selector. I will investigate in the direction you indicate, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This fixes the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was that a selector constructed and returned a new array each time it was called. Although this array was semantically the same each time the selector was called, it was not object identical. I resolved this by caching this array, and reusing it when the selector is called and should return a semantically the same array as the cached array.

Comment: You could use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) for this, it is part of the redux toolkit and I use it for [react with redux](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors). Besides memoizing it is also composable so you don't have repeating logic in your selectors.